# Does Octave have a ScaleProblem equivalent for fmincon?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm in the process of porting a large set of MATLAB scripts to Octave. Some of the scripts use the MATLAB Optimization toolbox, specifically the `fmincon` function. In the `optim` package in Octave, the `fmincon` function exists but has different parameters. Is there a way to replicate the `ScaleProblem` parameter in Octave's `fmincon`?

In my Octave script, I use `optimset`:

```
options = optimset('fmincon','Algorithm','sqp','ScaleProblem','obj-and-constr', ...);
```

Which causes the following warning:

```
warning: optimset: unrecognized option: ScaleProblem
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the trivial advise to write a wrapper that looks for this parameter-value pair, scales the matrices & calls fmincon without the `ScaleProblem` option, I can only emphasize to use the `NLopt`-toolbox from the MIT: https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ it got far more optimization algorithms with a neat matlab/octave interface, all open-source, and -- to my experience -- often more accurate and faster indeed =)